# How to capture in between / and / with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I currently have a URL that is any of this format:

```
https://example.com/f/random-id/text.text
http://example.io/f/random-id/test.mp4
www.example.co/f/random-id/123.doc
http://www.example.co/f/random-id/another.psd
```

I have been using a lot of `replace` just to manually strip it down a la:

```
url.replace("https://example.com/f/", "");
url.replace("text.text", "");
```

You get the horrible concept. I am trying to get the `random-id` and realized that using a RegEx would be a lot easier. Now I am struggling to come up with a working one.

I would appreciate any help in order to get `random-id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?[^/]+\/f\/(.*?)\/[^/]+$
```

and replace with `$1`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/HcyDN2/2

In JavaScript:

```
url.replace(/^(?:https?:\/\/)?[^/]+\/f\/(.*?)\/[^/]+$/g, '$1');
```

Comment: I am so sorry, but I forgot to mention that there might be different file names and extensions, that's why I just updated the answer. Thank you so much though. Looks so elegant, any more help for this scenario would be amazing

Comment: @ChrisPalmerBreuer: then just match "anything but forward slash" (`[^/]+$`) in the last part

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(
  [
    "https://example.com/f/random-id/text.text",
    "http://example.io/f/random-id/text.text",
    "www.example.co/f/random-id/text.text",
    "http://www.example.co/f/random-id/text.text"
  ].map(url => url.match(/\/f\/(.*?)\/text\.text/).pop())
)
// or as just a single entry
console.log(
  "https://example.com/f/random-id/text.text"
  .match(/\/f\/(.*?)\/text\.text/).pop()
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I just updated my question because the files could have different names and extensions as well. :(

Comment: Are there any rules for the extension? If not you might just use `/\/f\/(.*?)\/.*?\..*?/`.